# Code (CSS3 x jQuery) upgrade tips

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm just beginning in web design, and I've come up with this code to scroll to a place in the same page.

I don't know if this can or should be improved much longer, so I'm asking for any tips that can make this code better.

(I know its messy, gonna clean it later, just want to know if there's a better method).

I appreciate any help given! Follows the code.

## HTML

```
    <body>
    <section class="Container">
    <header class="TopHeader">
    <nav id="NavBar">
    <a id="Tecnologia">Tecnologia</a>
    </nav>
    </header>
    <article class="ConHome">
    ....    
    </article>
    <section id="BlankSpaceMenu">
    </section>
    <article class="ConTech">
    ...
    </article>
    </section>
    </body>
```

## CSS

```
    #BlankSpaceMenu{
    position:relative;
    height:7em;
    width:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,255,1);
    z-index:9;
    }
    .Container{
    position:relative;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
    }
    .TopHeader{
     position:fixed;
    background-color:rgba(255,153,0,1);
    color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
    height:7em;
    width:100%;
    z-index:10000;
    border-bottom:rgba(0,0,0,1) dashed 10px;
    }
    .ConHome{
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    height: 50em;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:10;
    }
    .ConTech{
    position: relative;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,255,1);
    color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
    height: 50em;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:8;
    }
```

## jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Tecnologia').click(function(){
    $(".ConHome").css('transition','all 0.4s ease');
    $(".ConHome").css('transform','translateY(-50em)');
    $("#BlankSpaceMenu").css('transition','all 0.4s ease');
    $('#BlankSpaceMenu').css('transform','translateY(-50em)');
    $(".ConTech").css('transition','all 0.4s ease');
    $(".ConTech").css('transform','translateY(-50em)');
    $(".TopHeader").css('transition','all 0.4s ease');
    $(".TopHeader").css('border-bottom-color','rgba(0,0,255,1)');
    })})
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on Code Review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I noticed and you can improve is the jQuery function which can be boiled down to much less lines of code, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { // DOM is ready
       $('#Tecnologia').click(function () { // Click-function


           $(".ConHome, #BlankSpaceMenu, .ConTech").css(
               {'transition':'all 0.4s ease', 
                'transform': 'translateY(-50em)'}
           );

           $(".TopHeader").css(
               {'transition':'all 0.4s ease',
                'border-bottom-color':'rgba(0,0,255,1)'}
           );


       }) // Click-function
   }) // DOM is ready
```

Notice that your 8 css-changes could be combined to 2, and that you can have several elements as jQuery selectors, when they are separated by comma.

Hope this helps you write shorter and (according to me) easier-to-manage code.

Comment: Hey! Thanks! That actually helped a lot improving the code. Plus, I could change the "translateY" and "transition" parts for a slideUp/SlideDown system.

Comment: @user3133486 That's correct! Good luck and happy coding :)